# What is this 8-tooth 10" circular saw blade intended for?

Tags: cutting, circular-saw, saw-blade

I came across this blade recently:

[image]

It is an 8-tooth 10" blade, part # `CB-108VA`.

Although I am familiar with the general principle that fewer teeth can be used for faster, rougher cuts this blade still seems a bit strange to me. Having only 8 teeth at this size seems especially rough, plus it has the very long arc sections between the teeth which seem like they would add some friction, or at least add no advantage I can think of.

Although on the blade it says "cutting of framing materials, plywood..." I'm a little skeptical of that. For plywood in particular I thought that having  a higher tooth count was generally recommended.

So, is this blade for some special purpose or circumstance?

Thanks

Comment: High tooth count for plywood and nicer veneers is recommended if you want to minimize tear-out. But this particular blade is intended for all purpose construction and the plywood they are talking about is construction grade or OSG exterior sheathing where no one cares about tear-out. Fast, all purpose construction blade when carbide was new and expensive. (as per the most recent answer.) The full tooth would leave plenty of relief for the tooth holder, which provide a lot of support for the tooth itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think (??) that it was a early carbide blade as carbide was really expensive to make, I have seen similar in old Sears catalogs.

Comment: Yes, this is what early carbide tipped crosscut/combo blades looked like in the old days. These were the sort that you would return when purchasing refurbished blades for a discount, used in heavy construction. The idea is that you traded having to sharpen tool steel blades regularly for carbide tipped blades that you traded-in as they dulled.

Answer (score 1):

8 Tooth blades that look exactly like that are still available in hardware stores. They are intended for cutting fiber cement siding.

Comment: That seems correct... given the apparent age of the blade I have, I wonder if it predates that type of material. Or maybe it is newer than it seems... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had one for years (just ruined it) and it works very well for heavy, rough cutting. Cuts much better on thick wood than other blades.

Answer (score 0):

Was an I A teacher for 30 years. We  used them all the time in shop class for ripping rough cut lumber. was the best thing going. I'm looking for one now to rip rough oak for  lobster trap runners. Can't find one.

Comment: Why were they specifically so good for ripping?

Comment: Get ye back to the classroom! The world _needs_ more kids taking shop.

Comment: @FreeMan NO! It's dangerous! I took many semesters of electronics, woodworking, and metalworking. And now I have too many interests, and a shop full of tools that I could be using _right now_ if I wasn't on SE. See how dangerous?

Comment: @jdv yeah... no, I don't see the problem... ;)